# what does slash(/) do in prolog?

Tags: prolog, operators

I have this code:

```
set_value(X,Value,[X/_|T],[X/Value|T]).
set_value(X,Value,[Y/V|T],[Y/V|NewT):- X\=Y,set_value(X,Value,T,NewT).
set_value(X,Value,[],[X/Value]).
```

But I cannot figure out what does / do. It looks like it pairs variables, but I'm not 100% sure. It definitely isn't division operator. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't *do* anything; it's used here to construct pairs, as you already figured.

Since the `/` doesn't occur on the right-hand side of `is` or in another place where arithmetic evaluation is performed, Prolog just produces two-argument terms with `/` as the functor. `/` is used because it can be written infix; `-` is also a popular choice for a generic pair constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct pairs"? What does constructing pairs do? I'm struggling to understand this answer.